# Is there a qpois() R equivalent in google sheet?

Tags: r, google-sheets, poisson

I want to calculate in Google Sheet the quantile function of Poisson distribution.

For example in R :

```
> qpois(p=0.90,lambda=5)
[1] 8
```

I have searched the web in order to find any equivalent function in google sheet but I haven't found anything.

Is there any function that I don't know or I came across ?

Comment: did you try: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094097?hl=en

Comment: @player0 yes but it calculates the dpois ppois equivalent in google sheet.Any help ? Do I miss something here ?

Comment: You can use the fact that poisson is a [limiting case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#As_a_Binomial_distribution_with_infinitesimal_time-steps) of binomial, thus `BINOM.INV(1000; 20/1000; 0.6)  ~~  qpois(0.6, 20)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poisson is a limiting case of binomial:

```
=BINOM.INV(100000, 5/100000, 0.9)
=8
```